# Java array of char of number to Integer

Tags: java, arrays, casting, integer

I need to read a file using BufferedReader, and on the second line i know there will always be 2 integers: 456 666 for example; but I don't know how many digits they will have, so after extracting the line (type String) with BufferedReader, I read char by char of that string to get the digits and add them to a array of char. When I have all the digits I fill the array with '\0'
Example:

```
array[0] = '4'
array[1] = '5'
array[2] = '6'
array[3] = '\0'
array[4] = '\0'
and so on
```

Now i wish to turn this array to an integer. 
I tried to first cast this array to a string and afterward apply Integer.parseInt but i does not work. I have no idea how to fix this problem. any help?

Comment: @LewsTherin: wouldn't that be a Strinteger?

Comment: @Wug Ha ha, except it is weird trying to say it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast an array to a String... But <strike>if you use spaces as fillers instead of `\0`, then</strike> you can do it like this:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(array).trim());
```

Regarding the comment - cool, `trim()` eliminates trailing `0x0` too:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    char[] chars = new char[5];
    chars[2] = '9';
    System.out.printf("Original length: %d%n",String.valueOf(chars).length());
    System.out.printf("Trimmed length:  %d%n",String.valueOf(chars).trim().length());
    System.out.printf("Parsed:          %d%n",Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(chars).trim()));
}
```

Comment: Even if you do use nulls as fillers you should still be able to do it this way.  You'll just get "456 " instead of "456", both of which `Integer.parseInt()` should be able to handle.

Answer (score 2):

What if you read just the line and attempt to parse it as an int. Since you don't know whether it is an integer use an exception to handle it:

```
String[] nextLine = reader.nextLine().split("\\s+") ;
Integer[] integer = new Integer[nextLine.length()] ;
try
{
  for(int i=0; i < nextLine.length();i++)  
   integer[i] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[i]) ;
}
catch(NumberFormatException exception)
{
  exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: there are two ints, so split the line on \s+ first

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead. From the documentation:

> A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.
>   A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.

A `Scanner` will use whitespace as its default delimiter, so you should be able to simply call `sc.nextInt()` for each expected integer token. See the linked page for usage examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `array` is your char array, this should do your work:

```
String str = "";
for (char c : array)
    str += c;

int result = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Comment: String.valueOf(array) is a much better way to do this.

Comment: @Wug good point. you are right :) but possibly valueOf() method is doing the same iteration to return the same string. am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using a `Scanner`.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
int first  = input.nextInt();
int second = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Assume an initial size of the array
    char array[] = new char[5];
    array[0] = '4';
    array[1] = '5';
    array[2] = '6';
    array[3] = '\0';
    array[4] = '\0';


    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length && array[i] != '\0'; i++){
        buffer.append(array[i]);
    }

    int myInteger = Integer.parseInt(buffer.toString());
```

If you want to create a String first and then parse it to an Integer, I suggest you use StringBuffer mainly because Strings in Java are immutable (you can't change a particular character in them). If you use StringBuffer you can work around this problem by applying toString method to the newly created object and then use Integer.parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you simply want to turn that array to characters into an integer, here is how you would do it.

char array[] = new char[5];

```
    array[0] = '4';
    array[1] = '5';
    array[2] = '6';
    array[3] = '\0';
    array[4] = '\0';

    String newString = String.copyValueOf(array);
    newString = newString.replace("\0", "");

    int newInt = Integer.parseInt(newString);

    System.out.println(array);
    System.out.println(newInt);
```

The above code has been tested and verified.

Comment: I want to add that you should be able to use newString = newString.trim(); as an alternative to newString = newString.replace("\0", "");

Answer (score 0):

Use String constructor `public String(char[] letters)` then `Integer.parseInt(...)`.